# How can I insert a character into a string with the s/// operator?

Tags: regex, perl, string

I'm trying to insert a comment character into a string something similar to this:

```
-CreateVideoTracker VT1 "vt name"
```

becomes

```
-CreateVideoTracker VT1 # "vt name"
```

The VT1 word can actually be anything, so I'm using the regex

```
$line =~ s/\-CreateVideoTracker \w/\-CreateVideoTracker \w # /g;
```

which gives me the result:

```
-CreateVideoTracker w #T1 "vt name"
```

Is there any way to do this with a single regex, or do I need to split up the string and insert the comment manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$line =~ s/^(\-CreateVideoTracker)\s+(\w+)/$1 $2 #/;
```

The bracketed expressions (known as "capture buffers") in the first half of the regexp are referenced as `$1`, `$2`. etc in the second half.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `\K` feature of Perl 5.10 regexs;

```
$line=~s/^\-CreateVideoTracker\s+\w+\K/ #/;
```

Comment: Good point! This `\K` switch is called ["zero-width positive look-behind assertion" (in the section on "Look-Around Assertions")](http://p3rl.org/http://perlre#Extended-Patterns) and I think it is superior to the old replacement mechanism using capturing and `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in:

```
$line =~ s/\-CreateVideoTracker \w/\-CreateVideoTracker \w # /g;
```

First, you want to match multiple character words, so in the left side, \w should be \w+.
Second, you can't use patterns like \w on the right side; instead capture what you want on the left with () and put it on the right with $1, $2, etc.:

```
$line =~ s/\-CreateVideoTracker (\w+)/\-CreateVideoTracker $1 # /g;
```